# ASP .net LocalReport on ReportViewer control not rendering for certian users

Tags: asp.net, .net, web-config, reportviewer

I have an issue with an ASP page I'm working on. I have a small site with a web.config for security. I added a new page and put it in a new folder so I can make a different web.config and add a few extra users to the allowed list (so they can only view this page). Works fine except this page has a ReportViewer control on it. The control itself will load but it will not render the local report. I have the local report file in the same folder as the aspx page. When the report is rendering it asks for authentication again a few times and then displays an empty, white ReportViewer control. So it must have something to do with inherited rights, maybe to the reports data source? Maybe the local report does security different from the web.config? The problem I have is I don't know enough keywords to ask the right question. Can anyone point me in the right direction? Thanks!

Comment: found this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8216186/report-viewer-web-control-version-10-gives-error-despite-set-up-correctly

Comment: <location path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>

Comment: If you've found the answer, why not write it up as an answer to your own question?  That way you can help others.

Comment: I cant for 5 hours as I have less then 10 reputation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this [Report Viewer Web Control Version 10 Gives Error Despite Set Up Correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8216186/report-viewer-web-control-version-10-gives-error-despite-set-up-correctly)

It looks like my issues was that the ReportViewer control was outside of the context of my main authorization list. So I just created another authorization list specifically for this control in web.config.

```
<location path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd"> 
    <system.web> 
        <authorization> 
            <allow users="*" /> 
        </authorization> 
    </system.web> 
</location>
```